# Required Validation Error Message is not getting displayed in jquery popup modal form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-post

I have used `ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` [Required] attribute for validation messages. The message is not getting displayed in my form. However, the RegularExpression validation and Range validation are working fine.

In one of my field, I used both [Required] and [RegualarExpression]. When I give the wrong input in the text box, the  RegualarExpression validation message appears and after erasing the input, then only Required validation message. Otherwise, Required validation message does not appear.

Here is my code:

--Model Class

```
    public class Email
    {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required!")]
    [RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]            {1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address.")]
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }


    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required!")]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

--View

```
    @{Html.EnableClientValidation();}

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">        </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmail", "LeaderBoard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data", id = "create-email-dialog" }))
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    {
    <form>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="popTable">
    <tr>
        <td width="38%">
            First Name:
        </td>
        <td width="62%">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="38%">
            Middle Name:
        </td>
        <td width="62%">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="38%">
           Last Name:
        </td>
        <td width="62%">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="38%">
            Email Address:
        </td>
        <td width="62%">
            <div class="errorMessage">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td width="38%">
             Status:
        </td>
        <td width="62%">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewData["Status"] as SelectList)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    <input type="button" id="btnCreateEmail" value="Save" name="submit" class="btn" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancel" class="closeDialog" />
    </form>

    }
    }
```

--Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateEmail()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
                var list = new SelectList(new[]
                {
                    new{Id = "Active", Name = "Active"},
                    new{Id = "Inactive", Name = "Inactive"}
                },
                "Id", "Name", 1);

            ViewData["Status"] = list;
            return PartialView("_CreateEmail");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEmail(Email model)
    {
        using (_emailRepository)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _emailRepository.Create(model);
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect? You need both messages displayed at the same time?

Comment: I'm a bit confused ? what are you expecting ?. You have mentioned the title as jquery popup modal but never termed it in your question

Comment: I need the [Required] error validation message to be shown. I am expecting this message to be shown in the fields like First Name and Last Name. The form is shown is jquery popup modal.

Comment: Are you saying that you need the [Required] error validation message to be shown on the page load itself?

Comment: NO. I want this either on tab change or in form submit

Answer (score 0):

Validate those fields in the document ready function

```
       $( document ).ready( function ( e )
        {

$( "form" ).validate().element( "#FirstName" );


$( "form" ).validate().element( "#LastName" );
});
```